# how to "foresee" string input?

Tags: c#, .net, eof

```
string inputString;
while ((inputString = Console.In.ReadLine()) != null)
{
magic...

for (var i = 1; i < bestHands.Count; i++)
    Console.Out.Write(
    table.DisplayCards(bestHands[i - 1].Item2.Cards())
    + (bestHands[i].Item1 == bestHands[i - 1].Item1 ? "=" : " ")
    + (i == bestHands.Count - 1 ? table.DisplayCards(bestHands[i].Item2.Cards()) : ""));

Console.Out.WriteLine();
}
```

We have the following code, the question is: can we somehow check if we get more input so that we do not have to move to a new line at the end of the program execution?

Comment: What is the `bestHands`? can you share minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it is a List<int, Hand> where Hand.Cards() returns a string.
output approx.:
Ac4d=Ad4s 5d6d As9s KhKd newline
Ac4d=Ad4s KhKd 5h6d As9s newline
5d6d Ac4d=Ad4s As9s KhKd newline

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski and the question is how not to output this last newline

Comment: `Console.Peek()` might help...

Answer (score 1):

Invert your thinking: print new line BEFORE each print - except for first time.

```
string inputString;
while ((inputString = Console.In.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //magic...

    bool needNewLine = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < bestHands.Count; i++)
    {
        if (needNewLine)
            Console.Out.WriteLine();
        else
            needNewLine = true;

        Console.Out.Write(
            table.DisplayCards(bestHands[i - 1].Item2.Cards())
          + (bestHands[i].Item1 == bestHands[i - 1].Item1 ? "=" : " ")
          + (i == bestHands.Count - 1 ? table.DisplayCards(bestHands[i].Item2.Cards()) : ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 1; i < bestHands.Count; i++)
                        Console.Out.Write(
                                        table.DisplayCards(bestHands[i - 1].Item2.Cards())
                                        + (bestHands[i].Item1 == bestHands[i - 1].Item1 ? "=" : " ")
                                        + (i == bestHands.Count - 1 ? table.DisplayCards(bestHands[i].Item2.Cards()) : ""));
                    if (Console.In.Peek() != -1)  
                        Console.Out.WriteLine();
```